# Apache Hadoop API to create unique directory atomically

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I am searching for method that creates the directories and throws error if directory already exists. Currently **Filesystem** class of **Apache Hadoop** has **mkdirs** method that simulate behavior of  **mkdir -p**. I am in search of API simulate **mkdir** in java.

`if fs.exists(path) 
     throw FileAlreadyExistsException("Directory exists") 
fs.mkdirs(path)`

This can be done but is susceptible to race condition. Do we have any API that can do this atomically.

Answer (score 1):

Afraid not. You can use rename() to rename a directory, with better guarantees about whether it will exist or not at the end.

you can create a file atomically on HDFS/posix filesystems through the hadoop APIs; you can use this as a cue for getting a lock on a directory tree. But you need to handle the problem of failure of the lock holder. This is why things tend to use ZK for this; it does offer guaranteed atomic/unique zknode creation.

FWIW, atomicity and filesystem operations are a bit of a mess. HDFS does actually make mkdirs() atomic, which is more than unix does, though that was an accident of implementation (holding on to a lock for performance). Once you start talking to object stores, all your preconceptions about atomic actions and overwrites need to be reset or your code will be unintentionally broken.